# Extracting value from a list of object[]

Tags: c#, firebird

I am working with a Firebird database, and the following code extracts some data:

```
FbDataReader reader = readCommand.ExecuteReader();

var rows = new List<object>();
while (reader.Read())
      {
       var columns = new object[reader.FieldCount];
       reader.GetValues(columns);
       rows.Add(columns);
      }
```

Now that I have my data read to "rows", it looks like this:

[image]

"ЛР КЛ1 220кВ" is the string value I need to extract.
The following code is supposed to do it:

```
var nameOfProperty = "property_name";
var propertyInfo = rows[1].GetType().GetProperty(nameOfProperty);
var value = propertyInfo.GetValue(rows[1], null);
```

I get System.NullReferenceException at the last line, because "property_name" must contain a real property name. How do I get correct property name?

Comment: It looks to me like you've combined a couple of approaches here.  One approach seems to be retrieving each "row" from the database as an object that has a property for each column in the table.  The other seems to be reading the values for a row into an array of objects, where the objects are the values you're looking for and there is no need to read properties at all.  Could it be that you're just piecing bits of code together without actually understanding what each bit is really doing?

Comment: The only property that `rows[1]` has is `Length` because it's an array instance. That reflection code might work if you had entity class instances, but arrays don't have properties other than `Length`.

Comment: I am not really familiar with this type of task, so I've tried different approaches to get the values and it could easily be that I've messed up.

Comment: I think the problem came from rows[]. Its return something else and you need an object[]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have list inside list.

Try :

```
...
var value = propertyInfo.GetValue(rows[1][0], null);
...
```

Comment: I tried, but VS tells me I cannot use [] indexing for an "object" type.

Comment: `rows[1]` will return `object`, not `object[]`, so it needs to be cast before the second indexer can be applied. This would be easier if you used `List<object[]>` since you're adding `object[]` instances to the list.

Comment: @madreflection You were 100% right. Works like a charm and I feel really bad for posting such a simple question.